# Lightbox with a custom field

Tags: 7, entities, javascript

Installed Lightbox2 plugin in my Drupal site. And created a image field. Copy the field--custom_field.tpl.php on my template folder. With the following:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
     <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div></a>
</div>
```

Now, i must include this code in my tpl file.

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
```

But i don't know how can i do? Thanks.

Comment: This `a` tag will automatically get added by Lightbox module.